# Program for pending files from a particular folder in a directory Progress 4gl

Tags: progress-4gl

Program for pending files from a particular folder in a directory, that file need to be with specific extension like xml. If the files are pending more than 5, then send a mail alert. Someone please help me. I am a rookie in progress 4gl.

Answer (score 3):

Code below will help you count the number of files in a folder. 
You will need some way of sending e-mails, that's nothing that Progress comes shipped with.

There's an old library called smptmail.p that you might be able to find online. Possibly there are better solutions out there as well.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile     AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE iXmlFiles AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.

DEFINE STREAM str.

INPUT STREAM str FROM OS-DIR("c:\temp\").
REPEAT :
    IMPORT STREAM str cFile.

    IF cFile MATCHES "*.xml" THEN 
        iXmlFiles = iXmlFiles + 1.
END. 
INPUT STREAM str CLOSE.         

IF iXmlFiles >= 5 THEN      
    MESSAGE "Alert. There are " iXmlFiles "xml files" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX WARNING.
```